# Is Grimlock stated to be the strongest dinobot in all versions of the Transformers universe?

Tags: transformers

In the Transformers G1 cartoon, Grimlock is stated to be the strongest dinobot.
However, certain events of the cartoon put doubts on this idea.

When battling Devastator, all dinobots except one are taken down by Devastator. Snarl, Sludge and Swoop are taken down once, Grimlock is taken down twice, and the only dinobot who isnt taken down by Devastator, and the only one who can take Devastator down is Slag.

There is also the event of the fight among the Dinobots. Sludge is taken down by Snarl. Swoop is taken down by Sludge. Snarl is taken down by Slag. Grimlock is taken down by Snarl and by Swoop, in 2 different times. And the only one who can't be taken down, only hold, it's Slag.

Also there is an episode where Grimlock is assumed dead, and Slag takes command of the Dinobots. Sludge who always follow the one he believes is the strongest doesnt question this.

Is there any version of the Transformers universe where Grimlock isnt stated to be the strongest dinobot and perhaps Slag is, or was Slag performance in the cartoon exagerated and Grimlock was always meant to be the strongest dinobot in all versions of the Transformers universe?

Comment: Where does the cartoon say that Grimlock is the strongest Dinobot? Other than Grimlock himself self-publicising?